# Finding latest file in directory

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get the latest `.png` file created in a directory: `output_folder_one`. Once find pass that file to `cv2` and `pytessercat` to print the captured text. However, I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'png'
```

could someone help me understand what's going on?

**Code:**

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
import glob

LatestFile = max(glob.iglob('output_folder_one'.png) , key=os.path.getctime)

image = cv2.imread(LatestFile)

test = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

print(test)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) means you are trying to access an attribute that don't existing for the object. in your case `.png` in the following string `'output_folder_one'.png`.

You have to change it as: `'output_folder_one/*.png'` where:

- The string contains the path to the directory to analyze. In your case `output_folder_one`
- The `*` means to get all the file
- The `.png` after the `*` means to get all the file with the specific extension.

```py
import os
import glob

LatestFile = max(glob.iglob('output_folder_one/*.png') , key=os.path.getctime)

print(LatestFile)
#OUTPUT: 'output_folder_one'.png (my last file)
```